How to generate the your-class.proto from C# object with decorators
I'm using protobuf-net to serial/deserialize the data to work with my Kafka cluster.
Is there any way to generate the class-name.proto from the C# class with decorators like the one below?
Thanks
jdang
class Person {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public Address Address {get;set;}
}
[ProtoContract]
class Address {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Line1 {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Line2 {get;set;}
}



So, looks like I can use this technique
string proto = Serializer.GetProto<YourType>();

